# Python: How to check if cell in CSV file is empty?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm reading in Python and I want the program to skip over the row if the first column is empty. How do I do this?

Right now I have:

```
with open('testdata1.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            if row[0] = null:
                #?????
```

How do I: 1) Check for empty cells in the CSV; and 2) tell the reader to skip the row?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
with open('testdata1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
        if not row[0]:
             print("12")
```

Reference:
[How do I detect missing fields in a CSV file in a Pythonic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278749/how-do-i-detect-missing-fields-in-a-csv-file-in-a-pythonic-way)

Comment: Great! What about skipping the row (as in not reading it, and moving to the next)?

Comment: if row[0] in (None, ""):
                continue

Comment: `if row[0] in (None, "")` can be more Pythonically written as `if not row[0]`

Comment: @jamylak `if not row[0]` will not mean the same as `if row[0] in (None, "")` in case of 0 as the value in the cell of a CSV.

Comment: @YDF That would be `"0"` not `0`

Comment: @jamylak not exactly. I mean here we are checking for an empty cell in the CSV. Whereas a `0` as an integer value in the condition `if not row[0]` will result in true indicating that the cell is empty which is actually not the case.

Comment: @YDF But coming from `csv.reader` it would always have string values so that would never happen, unless I'm mistaken, that's why that case would not happen

Answer (score 3):

You could use try and except.

```
for row in csvreader:
        try:
               #your code for cells which aren't empty
        except:
               #your code for empty cells
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out what happens if you print and empty row and it returns [] (empty brackets)... so just check for that.

```
with open('testdata1.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        if row == []:
            continue
        #do stuff normally
```

Comment: Also instead of continue an else statement is possible...

Answer (score 0):

After hour of trying I was able to do it

```
while act_tab.cell(row=i, column=1).value is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Small adaptation of Kit Fung's answer:

```
with open('testdata1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    if not row[0]:
         continue  # this will skip to the next for loop iteration
    # do your processing here
```

Comment: `if not row[0]` will not account the same for `0` as the value in the cell of a CSV then for something like `None or ""`.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume if you `len()` it then would be zero i.e.

```
if not len(row[0])
```