# Replacing Empty Cells with 0 in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I am using the csv module to read in csv files to do data analysis.

```
data = []
c1 = []
c2 = []
c3 = []
data_file = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
for row in data_file:
       data.append(row)
for i in data:
       c1.append(data[i][0])
       c2.append(data[i][1])
       c3.append(data[i][2])
```

How do I replace the empty cells with 0?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes `data[i][j]` is just the empty string and in that case you want to insert in the corresponding `ci` list a `0`? If this is your issue you can fix this by using `or`: `c1.append(data[i][0] or '0')`

Answer (score 0):

before appending your data you could do a check similar to what is found here :

[Python: How to check if cell in CSV file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192705/python-how-to-check-if-cell-in-csv-file-is-empty)

When the condition is true, simply append 0 to your corresponding cell (c1, c2, c3)