# Reading a csv file in Python with the module csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, module

I'm trying to read a csv file in Python using the module csv. 
To do that, I use a reader variable :

```
 with open('oneOrganization.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile2:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader2:
        if row["role"] == []:
            row_dict['Role'] = "User"
        else:
            row_dict['Role'] = row["role"]
```

However, running the program, I realize that it does get in the loop at all although the cvs file exists and is indeed called oneOrganization.csv. What could be the reason of that ?

I'm starting in Python,  usually this method works.

Comment: `oneOranization.csv` or `oneOrganization.csv` ?? and check current path. also post error message, we cannot guess otherwise.

Comment: How could we answer without having the csv file itself ? But if you're on windows, you definitly want to open the file in "rb" mode ("read binary"), and let the csv module deal with newlines. Also, beware that using relative path is brittle at best (as it will be resolved against the current working directory which can be just anything at runtime).

Comment: traceback error message would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Sorry it is oneOrganization.csv. 
Concerning the path it should be ok.
There is not any error message, it just doesn't pass through the loop.

Comment: what do you get if you `print reader2`

Comment: Can you provide the content of the file and the output if you print all lines?

Comment: try without `newline=''` that seems an odd thing to have there - doesn't that mean starting a new line every time it matches an empty string? What does that even do?

Comment: @Stael this is the recommended way to open files if you use them with `csv`.

Comment: but for reading it is not very useful.

Comment: @Stael, the `newline=''` means that the file is read in universal newline mode but the newline sequences are passed through to the reader unchanged. So it is indeed the recommended way to use the `csv` module and no need to open the file 'rb'.

Comment: @Stael : When I print reader2, I get : 
<csv.DictReader object at 0x0000002FB0C096A0>

Comment: @P.Siehr : The content file is a singe line : 
"roleAssignmentId,roleId,role,assignedTo,assignedToUser,scopeType,orgUnitId,orgUnit"

I'm starting to think that reader2 is empty at that point, that would explain why it doesn't get in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that prevents your code from accessing the if loop `if row['Role']==[]` is because you're trying to find empty elements the wrong way.
try this instead:

Method 1:

```
with open('oneOrganization.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if row['test1'] in (None,''): # to check if cell is empty
            row_dict['Role'] = "User"
        else:
            row_dict['Role'] = row["role"]
```

Method 2: provided by @Jean-François Fabre

```
with open('oneOrganization.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if not row['test1']:
            row_dict['Role'] = "User"
        else:
            row_dict['Role'] = row["role"]
```

Method 3 : "elegant one liner" - by @Jean-François Fabre

```
with open('oneOrganization.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        row_dict['Role'] = row["role"] or "User"
```

I tried it on a csv example that can be represented like this: (np.array form)

```
[['test1' 'test2' 'test3']
 [   1       2       3   ]
 [   11      22      33  ]
 [           222     333]]
```

and used this code:

```
import csv

with open('test_csv.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row['test1'] in (None,''):
            print('no')
        else:
            print(row['test1'])
```

or with method 2:

```
import csv

with open('test_csv.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if not row['test1']:
            print('no')
        else:
            print(row['test1'])
```

or method 3

```
import csv

with open('test_csv.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['test1'] or 'no')
```

output:

```
1
11
no
```

you can refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192705/python-how-to-check-if-cell-in-csv-file-is-empty) for more informations about how to check if a "cell" is empty in a csv file.

Comment: `if row['test1']:` is enough ("falsy")

Comment: OP's question was about entering the `for` loop. What's an `if` loop anyway?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille the for loop has no problem, he must be confusing it with entering the if loop i think, at least test gave nothing as for the for loop.

Comment: @RayhaneMama I think you're right, I see why the OP thought that the loop was never entered.

Comment: elegant one liner: `row_dict['Role'] = row['test1'] or "User"`

Comment: God you're on fire xD added too, thanks for your plus @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @RayhaneMama :) I just saw that yesterday in a nice answer. `or` isn't used enough like this.